# Frequency of items in a list in R

Tags: r, histogram

I have a very large csv file. I want to calculate the frequency of the items in the second column in order to graph histogram. An example of my data:

```
0010,10.1.1.16
0011,10.2.2.10
0012,192.168.2.61
0013,192.168.173.19
0014,10.2.2.10
0015,10.2.2.10
0016,192.168.2.61
```

I have used the below:

```
  inFile <- read.csv("file.csv")
  summary(inFile)
  hist(inFile$secondCol)
```

output of summary:

```
  X0010                X10.1.1.16
  Min.   :11.00   10.2.2.10     :3   
  1st Qu.:12.25   192.168.173.19:1   
  Median :13.50   192.168.2.61  :2   
  Mean   :13.50                      
  3rd Qu.:14.75                      
  Max.   :16.00
```

Because the file is very large, I'm not getting the right histogram. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `table`.

```
DF <- structure(list(V1 = 10:16, V2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
             2L, 4L), .Label = c("10.1.1.16", "10.2.2.10", 
             "192.168.173.19", "192.168.2.61"), class = "factor")), 
             .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", 
             row.names = c(NA, -7L))

table(DF$V2)
#     10.1.1.16      10.2.2.10 192.168.173.19   192.168.2.61 
#         1              3              1              2
```

If you want a data.frame out of this, you can use `as.data.frame`:

```
as.data.frame(table(DF$V2))
#             Var1 Freq
# 1      10.1.1.16    1
# 2      10.2.2.10    3
# 3 192.168.173.19    1
# 4   192.168.2.61    2
```

Since you say you want a `histogram`, this can be done directly using `ggplot2` *without* having to get the counts first as follows:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = DF, aes(x = V2)) + geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..))
```

[image]

Comment: I agree but my problem that the file is very large can't be opened with R. That's why I'm reading the values one by one. Therefore, I need to fill the list first then apply the histogram. The question how to fill the list based on the frequency of the item.

Comment: which R version (and 32- or 64-bit) are you using and how big is your data?

Comment: R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26),Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit). I have more than one file and size varying. Sizes in Gb.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to debug your code. But in the mean while, have you checked the package [**bigdata**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigdata/index.html)??

Comment: No, I will check it , seems a package to handle the large file. Thank you.

Comment: sure, check SO for posts using `bigdata` as well to quickly get to know the usage. I've no access to a GB size csv. And I've no patience to create one. Else, I'd like to try the package as well.

Comment: You could also try to get the result using `awk` + `sort` + `uniq` from a shell like so: `awk -F',' '{print $2}' in.txt | sort -k1,1n | uniq -c > out.txt`. And then hopefully that's smaller to import in R and plot.

Comment: thank you it works. I applied my filter then your filter and the file size was reduced. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We could have also done a as.numeric() on the column.

```
typeof(data$hourofcrime)
# gives me a list
#> typeof(data$hourofcrime)
#[1] "list"
hour_crime_rate <- as.numeric(data$hourofcrime)
hist(hour_crime_rate)
```